# How to modify decal limit?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

As being able to see all bullet holes, explosion impacts and blood stains created in a match gives an tactical advantage in competitive multiplayer, I would like to experiment with unlimited or highest possible decal limit.
I know that Source games generally limit decals to 200 by default (in some Valve games there's a setting in advanced options, CS:GO has no in-game option).

`r_decals` may have worked in the past, now the command doesn't exist.

Comment: You can clear them with a command, but keeping them is not possible. Also the server would or should prevent that anyway. In Source games the final limit was set by the server (usually 200) and the client limit could not exceed it.

Comment: @dly: I didn't know that the limit is set by the server. I don't know why you didn't post an answer, feel free to do so.

Comment: I have no confirmed source for it for CS GO, that's why I commented instead of posting an answer. I can only confirm it for Source.

Answer (score -1):

Decal limit is tied to your graphics settings, specifically your shader detail. The higher you have your shader details set, the more decals your game will show. It also changes how many decals can overlap at once. 3Kliksphilip has a good video detailing how decals work that can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pX4Drlo0Z1E).

He worked it out to be roughly:
Low - 1024 decals
Medium - 1024 decals
High - 2048 decals
Very high - 4096 decals

He also saw that when shader details are set to low, bullet holes and such do not show up on props, so it is recommended to have them be as high as you can go without losing those all-important frames.